# How to upload all files & sub directory in a directory to sharepoint

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint, ubuntu-16.04, file-transfer

I'm writing an automation script to transfer files & subdirectory in a directory to SharePoint from ubuntu. And I'm able to transfer the files from in a directory but failed when uploading the subdirectories.

For reference my code

```
#importing required packages
import sys
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from config import config
import os


#Reading the configuration variables
username=config['sp_user'].split("@")[0]
password=config['sp_password']
sharepoint_url=config['sp_base_path']
sp_folder_url=config['folderUrl']
path=config['path']
domain=config['domain']
domain_username=domain+'\\'+username


#Reading the files from Linux
files = next(os.walk(path))[2]


for i in range(0, len(files)):
    filename = files[i]
    requestUrl = sharepoint_url + '/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(\'' + sp_folder_url + '\')/Files/add(url=\'' + filename + '\',overwrite=true)'
    with open( filename, 'rb') as file_input:
        try:
             headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=verbose', 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'}
             r = requests.post(sharepoint_url + "/_api/contextinfo",auth=HttpNtlmAuth(domain_username,password), headers=headers)
             formDigestValue = r.json()['d']['GetContextWebInformation']['FormDigestValue']
             headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=verbose', 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'x-requestdigest' : formDigestValue}
             uploadResult = requests.post(requestUrl,auth=HttpNtlmAuth(domain_username,'password'), headers=headers, data=file_input.read())


        except Exception as err: 
            print("Some error occurred: " + str(err))
```

May I know what should I need to achieve that and please help me to bridge the gap between my requirement. Could you please try to produce my code. Thanks in advance

## UPDATE

I'm getting following error when uploading the files now.

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows the request has not got authenticated. I suggest you take advantage of below python library for SharePoint :

- https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

And there is a similar thread you may take a reference:

- [upload files from Linux to share point using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990780/convert-the-powershell-script-to-python-3/61996532#61996532)