# Convert the Powershell script to Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to perform an upload files from Linux to share point using Python. However I tried a lot by googling but nothing help. At last I got a power shell script that is working.  So requesting for help to convert the below script to Python 3

```
Specify tenant admin and site URL
$User = "justin.jacob@spidersoft.in"
$SiteURL = "https://test-my.sharepoint.com/personal/justin_jacob_spidersoftin";


$Folder = "C:\Users\justin.jacob\Desktop\New folder"
$DocLibName = "Documents"

#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site – required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"


$Password  = ConvertTo-SecureString ‘123@123’ -AsPlainText -Force


#Bind to site collection
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)


$Context.Credentials = $Creds

#Retrieve list
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("$DocLibName")


$Context.Load($List)



$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Upload file
Foreach ($File in (dir $Folder -File))
{
$FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
$FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
$Upload = $List.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$Context.Load($Upload)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

Comment: Powershell is available for Linux...

Comment: But I need to convert to python as per my requirement

Comment: Why the requirement to use Python? Just use what works - your Powershell script.

Comment: It is need to integerate with other python scripts as framework

Comment: Just use PowerShell and call the Python scripts from the PowerShell script or vice versa. There is no tool to convert PowerShell to Python or vice versa, it's a manual process, and one trying to do this needs to have full knowledge of both. You are literally asking folks here to do your work for you. Since we are here to help with PowerShell code issues, this is not a PowerShell code issue. So, really off-topic if that is your specific ask. You have also cross-posted this to other Q&A sites as well. SP StackExchange for example:

Comment: So, maybe you can leverage these resources to learn what you need to know to get you to where you want to be. Yet again, Powershell can call Python code and Python can call Powershell code.    [PowerShell Guide to Python](https://leanpub.com/PowerShell-to-Python)   ---   [PowerShell To Python And Back](https://blog.ipswitch.com/powershell-to-python-and-back-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you want to upload files to sharepoint, you can take a reference of below code:

```html
import os
from config import config
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version

# get data from configuration
username = config['sp_user']
password = config['sp_password']

authcookie = Office365('https://xxx.sharepoint.com', username=username, password=password).GetCookies()

site = Site('https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/abc',version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
spfolder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/testfolder')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"D:\mytestfolder"): 
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
        print(filepath)

        # perform the actual upload
        with open(filepath, 'rb+') as file_input:
            try: 
                spfolder.upload_file(file_input, file)
            except Exception as err: 
                print("Some error occurred: " + str(err))
```

The code uses following python library:

- https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/files.html

Comment: Thanks @Baker_Kong_MSFT. May I know is it possible to upload subdirectories like this

Comment: Do you want to create sub folder in SP? if so, you can use "folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/This Folder')" https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/files.html

Comment: Or you can use this rest endpoint to add folder: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1198479/How-can-I-create-folder-and-subfolder-in-sharepoin